# Java loops using a Scanner class and I can use breaks

Tags: loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am trying to figure out how to use the scanner class with a loop.  I cannot use break as part of my code.  I am unsure how close I am, but any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);  
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
    int number = i.nextInt();
    boolean value = number>=1 && number <=10;
    while (number >=1 && number <=10){
        System.out.println ("Good Job!");
    }
        if  (number <=1 && number >=10  )
            continue;
        {System.out.print ("You have entered an incorrect number. Please try again");

            System.out.println("Please try again:");

            Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
            return;
                    }
```

Comment: This code won't compile from what I can tell.  Is there something significant about not being able to use `break`?

Comment: The instructor does not want us to use break.  He wants us to find another way to close the loop.

Comment: Can you clean up the code in your question?  This would make it easier for people to give you a response.

Comment: I actually think you are already on the right track.  Instead of using `break`, you can have some state which is checked at each iteration of a `while` loop.  When the condition fails, then the loop will terminate without the use of `break`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for you comments.  That's my issue, I am very new to Java, I am not sure how to clean up my code.  I was working on this for close to six hours yesterday.  It's a little embarrassing for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner class can be used like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // now loop while the scanner is available
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        // print out every single number input from standard input
        System.out.println("Scanner inputed from stdin is " + Integer.toString(scanner.nextInt()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class ScannerDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String next = scan.next();
            if("quit".equals(next)) break;
            System.out.println("Element: " + next); 
        }

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Press `quit` to exit.